# C++ parse a file and store contents into a map

Tags: c++

I am new, I parsed this text file and I am trying to store its contents into a map and print them out. I can't seem to get the itr to work.

this is the text file

```
addq Src,Dest  
subq Src,Dest 
imulq Src,Dest 
salq Src,Dest 
sarq Src,Dest
shrq Src,Dest 
xorq Src,Dest 
andq Src,Dest 
orq Src,Dest 
incq Dest 
decq Dest 
negq Dest 
notq Dest
```

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class CPU {
    
    map<int, int, long> registers;
    
    
};

class ALU{
    int add, sub, mul, divide;
    
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string line;
    string ins, src, dest;
    ifstream myfile("/Users/feliperivas/Documents/CPUProject/CPUProject/instrunction.txt");
    map<string, string> registers;
    

    while(getline(myfile, line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, ins,',');
        getline(ss, src,',');

        registers.insert(pair<string, string>(ins, src));
        cout << line << endl;

// for (auto itr = registers.begin();
//          itr != registers.end(); ++itr) {
//         cout << itr->first << '\t'
//              << itr->second << '\n';
    }
    

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *I can't seem to get the itr to work.* is a weak problem description. You are much better off if you describe what happens complete with any error or warning messages. Without a description of what you expect, all we have to go on is the code, and if the code is known to be incorrect, we can't know what the output should be.

Comment: I recommend having an `Instruction` class as the base.  You may want to have to children, `Binary_Instruction` and `Unary_Instruction`.    The `Instruction` class will contain all common members and functionality of all instructions.  For example all instructions have a name, and a destination parameter.  The `Binary_Instruction` will contain common methods and members for instructions with two parameters, such as appending a source parameter.  You may want to have an "execute" abstract function in Instruction, which the leafs need to implement.

Comment: @TrifecticBlade What is `map<int, int, long>` supposed to be?  A `map` can't hold 3 values. Also, your `getline(ss, ins,',');` call is wrong, it should be `getline(ss, ins, ' ');` instead. Beyond that, the rest of the code is fine, including the code you commented out. So why do you say it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
map<string, string>::iterator itr;
for (itr = registers.begin(); itr != registers.end(); ++itr) 
{
    // " : " separates itr->first and itr->second. Can be changed.
    std::cout << itr->first << " : " << itr->second << std::endl;
}
```

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

class CPU 
{
    //std::map<int, int, long> registers;
};

class ALU 
{
    int add, sub, mul, divide;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    std::string line;
    std::string ins, src, dest;
    std::ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    
    std::map<std::string, std::string> registers;

    while (getline(myfile, line)) 
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::getline(ss, ins, ',');
        std::getline(ss, src, ',');

        registers.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(ins, src));
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = registers.begin(); itr != registers.end(); ++itr) 
    {
        std::cout << itr->first << " : " << itr->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also std::map<int, int, long> registers; does not make sense as maps can only store 2 values. So remove it.

Also, you should not use the following line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

...as it's considered as bad practice.